# this is my first applet. but when i run is using either eclipse or web browser all i get is an empty applet screen. what went wrong?

Tags: java, html, applet, japplet

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
//basic applet
public class test2 extends JApplet
{
//print method
    public void print(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("Black Mamba", 50, 50);
        g.drawRect(25, 25, 50, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: First recommendation: do not write Applets. This is obsolete technology.

Comment: Name your method `paint()` and NOT  `print()` so it could get called by the Applet Lifecycle. [Read this for more](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/5503/applets)

Comment: why are applets obsolete? what replaced them? @RealSkeptic

Comment: They are obsolete because of poor browser support, and the ability nowadays to get much more from the browser through Javascript and HTML5. What to do instead depends on the reason why you wanted to write an applet in the first place.

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). *"why are applets obsolete?"* Continual security bugs led browser manufacturers to discontinue support. *"what replaced them?"* HTML 5 and JS. **Edit:** given the code above, *".. and the HTML 5 `canvas`"*